Using the scrapy framework, I encountered an error ('SSL routines', '', 'dh key too small')
When using the scrapy framework to request a URL, the control prints the following information: twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', '', 'dh key too small')]>], what code do I need to add to the middlewares.py file to solve this problem?
(python version is 3.10.4, scrapy version is 2.11.1, Twisted version is 22.4.0)

It's possible that this website just can't be accessed with your OpenSSL version.

As I guessed, nobody has a generic advice for this, so you should provide the actual URL to get a specific answer (which, as I said, may be "not possible").
